# Is changing the current working directory in iOS a safe thing to do?

Tags: iphone, ios4, filesystems, directory, ipad

I was wondering if changing the current working directory in iOS could affect some of the standard behavior of the frameworks provided by Apple. I guess every method that uses some path or name (e.g. `[UIImage imageNamed]`) works with absolute directories, but can I rely on that? Also, is changing the directory to the Documents directory a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the current working directory should not break anything. Well written code doesn't break due to some unstated constraint such as "you must be in this directory".

There's not much point in changing the current working directory to the Documents directory. The code you write shouldn't be depending on an assumption about the current working directory -- aim to use absolute paths.